# How can I create a virtual Ethernet device in C?

Tags: c, linux

I am writing a program in C that needs to interface with virtual Ethernet devices. Here are some examples of commands that I could write in Shell, that I want to incorporate into my C program:

```
ip link add A type veth peer name B
ip addr add 172.17.42.1/16 dev A
ip link set A up
ip link set B netns 123
```

I did some searching but I couldn't find the commands/libraries that I need to perform this sort of operation. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Use the [source](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/iproute2) Luke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot create any virtual Ethernet device in portable C11 (or portable C99) because the C standard does not have any notion of Ethernet devices.

You need some operating system support for that, and your question becomes operating system specific.

If you are targeting the Linux operating system, you could use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand the [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) executed by your `ip` commands.

However, you could simply write some application-specific shell script (running the above commands) and *carefully* use [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) or [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) to run it (or even use directly [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) etc... read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) for more). Be scared of potential [code injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection), and if you build the command string, check any input data entering it.

As [ysdx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/637866/ysdx) commented, look inside [rtnetlink(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/rtnetlink.7.html)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. I did mean Linux - compatibility on other operating systems is not needed. I'll have a look at strace - thanks! Also, I want to avoid popen etc.

Comment: All of this, is implemented with netlink sockets AFAIK (and probably mostly NETLINK_ROUTE). See "man 7 rtnetlink".